# ASYNC recaptcha joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I have a problem with **PHP** and **Joomla**.

When I tested my website with SEO tool, there was a message about 2 blocking script

> "Your page has 2 blocking script resources and 3 blocking CSS
>   resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page."

So I try to async resources to unblock rendering my site.

First is $file  = `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js';`

and second 
$file = '`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.jsonload=JoomlaInitReCaptcha2&render=explicit&hl=' . JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();`

Below is the code I tried and can someone help me to put **async** in the right way?

```
public function onInit($id = 'dynamic_recaptcha_1')
{
    $pubkey = $this->params->get('public_key', '');

    if ($pubkey === '')
    {
        throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_RECAPTCHA_ERROR_NO_PUBLIC_KEY'));
    }

    if ($this->params->get('version', '1.0') === '1.0')
    {
        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

        $theme  = $this->params->get('theme', 'clean');
        $file   = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js';

        JHtml::_('script', $file);
        JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery( document ).ready(function()
            {Recaptcha.create("' . $pubkey . '", "' . $id . '", {theme: "' . $theme . '",' . $this->_getLanguage() . 'tabindex: 0});});');
    }
    else
    {
        // Load callback first for browser compatibility
        JHtml::_('script', 'plg_captcha_recaptcha/recaptcha.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true)); 

        $file = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=JoomlaInitReCaptcha2&render=explicit&hl=' . JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
        JHtml::_('script', $file);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You might like to post your question on the Joomla Stack Exchange site to gain the attention of a more dedicated audience. Note, in your Administrator -> Help tab, the 2nd last item says Stack Exchange <-- this is where the Joomla team encourages you to post your Joomla-specific questions and issues when you need support.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the following line:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'plg_captcha_recaptcha/recaptcha.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
```

to:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'plg_captcha_recaptcha/recaptcha.min.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true), array('async'=>'async'));
```

See [this post](https://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-load-javascript-files-asynchronously-in-joomla-3-8) for a guide on how to load JS files asynchronously on Joomla.